# Looking for a linguistic term

Tags: terminology, phonotactics

I'm trying to pinpoint a linguistic concept that may or may not exist.

Let's say you have a complete set of "units" (i.e., sounds/letters/moras) in a language. This can be many things, depending on the language.
If the language has an alphabet, this set of units may be the alphabet itself. If there isn't any 1-to-1 mapping between sounds and the alphabet, this set of units may be a set of sounds (i.e., in English, just the letter "a" has multiple readings). It can also be a complete set of sounds (e.g., moras, expressed with Hiragana in Japanese).

You randomly select a reasonable amount of such units and attach them together, forming an artificial "word".
Obviously, this artificial "word" may or may not be a real word in that specific language.
I believe that the probability of such an artificial word constituting a real word is different across language so language families.
If this probability is relatively high, it would mean that a large percentage of "garbled", artificial sounds produced in that language would actually constitute real words.

In that case, the language in question would have a large degree of <the term I am looking for>, e.g., some sort of *saturation*, perhaps "phonetic saturation"?

I would appreciate any opinions or tips!

Comment: I am not aware of a specific term for the rate of usage of the allowed space of words in a given language.

Comment: In programming sometimes we call this _semantic density_.

Comment: @ngn Thanks, looks like semantic density is a good starting point!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the concept you are looking for is discussed in *The sound pattern of English* pp. 416 ff. where an algorithm is posited to compute a scalar "distance from lexicon". The point of that computation is to distinguish existing words like [brɪk] from possible non-extant words [blɪk] (they apparently did not know of the existence of that art supply store when they wrote this) vs impossible [bnɪk] and highly-impossible [bnzk]. Their system is based on a phonetic theory of "similarity", where [b] and [p] are more similar than [b] and [ʃ] in computable ways.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into it.